# mongo jpa between query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jpa

I'm using spring jpa to integrate with a mongo database. I've got a simple mongo document with an `Instance` field. In my repository I've tried something like

```
findByInstantBetween(Instant start, Instant end, Pageable pageable);
```

I've got a simple spring unit test (run with spring runner and a normal spring context) that looks like this:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

...


@Test
public void testSearchByInstantBetween() {
    // insert a document before the date range to test, should not be retrieved by query
    MyDocument doc = new MyDocument();
    doc.setInstant(Instant.now());
    doc= docRepository.insert(doc);

    // insert a document with the start instant, should be retrieved
    doc.setId(null);
    Instant start = Instant.now();
    doc.setInstant(start);
    doc = docRepository.insert(doc);

    // insert a document with the end instant, should be retrieved
    doc.setId(null);
    Instant end = Instant.now();
    doc.setInstant(end);
    doc = docRepository.insert(doc);

    // insert a document after the end instant, should not be retrieved
    doc.setId(null);
    doc.setInstant(Instant.now());
    doc = docRepository.insert(doc);

    // check that 4 documents have been inserted
    assertThat(docRepository.findAll()).hasSize(4);

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 5);

    // run between query, expected size is 2
    Page<MyDocument> docs = docRepository.findByInstantBetween(start, end, pageable);
    assertThat(docs.getContent()).hasSize(2); // <-- this fails with expected 2, found 0
}
```

I've also tried to change the query method as follows

```
findByInstantGreaterThanEqualAndInstantLessThanEqual(Instant start, Instant end, Pageable pageable);
```

And when I run the test with this method I get

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException: Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDocument, you can't add a second 'instant' expression specified as 'instant: Document{{$lte=2019-10-15T06:28:43.508Z}}'. Criteria already contains 'instant : Document{{$gte=2019-10-15T06:28:43.505Z}}'.
```

Has anyone had this kind of problem?

Comment: The first method works fine, that is instantBetween is perfectly fine, that's why it returns zero docs.
The Second method signature is wrong and you cannot use that for your requirement.
The only way is to use @Query annotation and write the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Between` query method was working correctly. I didn't know it was exclusive, so since I only had a test case with two elements (`start` and `end` `Instant`s respectively) the query looked between (not including) those and found 0 elements.

When I added another element with an `Instant` in the middle of `start` and `end`, I expected 3 but it returned 1.

In order to make the query inclusive I annotated it as follows

```
@org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query("{ instant: {$gte: ?0, $lte: ?1}}")
```

where `?0` and `?1` correspond with the `start` and `end` parameters respectively.

Hopefully this can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Use below example query for finding something with greater or equal and less than or equal.

```
@Query("{instant : {$gte : ?0, $lte : ?1}}")
 findUsingQ(Instant start, Instant end, Pageable pageable);
```